# How can I fix this : Warning: the fonts "Times" and "Times" are not available for the Java logical font "Serif"

Tags: java, macos, fonts, anylogic

system：Mac OS
software：AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.7.6
language: Java

When I run my model, the console print this info:

> Warning: the fonts "Times" and "Times" are not available for the Java logical font "Serif", which may have unexpected appearance or behavior. Re-enable the "Times" font to remove this warning.

Comment: Bug [JDK-8273358: _macOS Monterey does not have the font Times needed by Serif_](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8273358) is fixed.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

We also recently had this issue on a mac running the latest public beta of Monterey.

For some reason the Times font was no longer installed or active on the Mac.

You can check in FontBook

[image]

You can simply reinstall it

I struggled to find a source online - her is one suggestion - https://www.freebestfonts.com/timr45w-font

Comment: Yep - I seem to have been hit by this generating Asciidoctor documents, since upgrading to Monterey (not beta). Adding the Times font as you mention seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Had the same problem, worked for me, too. Thanks!

Comment: Also had this problem with PlantUML, this fixed it.

Comment: I don't want to install Times. I already have Times New Roman. I'd rather not install a font from a web site I don't know very well. Why doesn't Java use that as "Times"? And is there a way to fix that?

Comment: That font seems to be break rendering of text set in Times in recent Chromium versions.

Answer (score 10):

To install an OSX legacy font, such as Courier or Times, do the following:

Go to your system's font folder: `/System/Library/Fonts`.

Find the font you want with the TTC extension.

Drag it to Font Book and authorize its installation with your administration password.

It should now be in the `~/Library/Fonts` folder.

Open Transfonter in your browser [https://transfonter.org/].

Select Unpack TTC and Upload.

Navigate to the *.ttc file you want and open it.

When conversion is complete, download the ZIP archive file and open it.

Drag all the *.ttf fonts into Font Book and install, using your administration password.

It will now be found as an active font in "All Fonts."

Comment: Make sure that all font variants are installed. When I dragged them into the Font Book app, only one of the font variants was installed. Double click all them works for me.

Comment: You can skip the step of dragging the TTC into Font Book, just drag it straight onto the Unpack TTC website.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this problem myself on OSX Monterey. Resolved it by upgrading to the latest version of Azul Zulu OpenJDK 15, which no longer has the dependency on the discontinued Times font (I think it uses the very similar Times New Roman instead).

Comment: I'm just now joining this party,(MaOS Ventura 13.2.1 on Apple silicon and Java 11.04) and Jaco-Ben's solution was nice and clean---although it worries me about having to support my eventual users.